# Validation of textbox on Keypress event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work on a validation of textbox on Keypress.

Required Validation:

Textbox should not allow user to enter any other(alert message on entering any other alphabet/digit)character than A-H and 0-9 and only format should be allowed is A0:00:CB:D2 i.e any combination can be there but it should contain alphabet from A-H only and digits 0-9 and after each two characters should be there and seperator should only be :

Comment: have you tried anything yet? done any research on form validation?  or do you just want someone to write your code for you?

Comment: Hi Chris,Yes I worked on this and yes I am able to do the validation but I felt my approach was not generic so posted it.What I tried so far a) I am checking/storing the entered in a variable b)I did validation for individual character means from A to H but I couldn't make it generic implementation i.e I am able to validate only in case when length of entered variable is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML5 form validation:

```
<input pattern="([A-H\d]{2}:)*[A-H\d]{2}">
```